# Linq contains from ListItems

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to return records from the program table that match the items in passed list but I am getting the following error:

*Argument type 'System.Nullable' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'*

```
void PopulateEvents(List<ListItem> programs)
{
    var rows = from table in db.Events.AsEnumerable()
               where programs.Contains(table.ProgramID)
               select Events;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void PopulateEvents(List<string> programs)
{
    var rows = db.Events.Where(i => programs.Contains(i.ProgramID)).Select(i => db.Events);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `AsEnumerable()`, because it will bring down the entire `Events` table and execute your query with `linq-to-objects`.

Regardless of whether you choose to remove `AsEnumerable()`, I would modify your query to use the `Any` operator instead of the `Contains` method and you need to use the property from the `ListItem` that matches the `ProgramID` property. That should resolve your error message.

```
 var rows = from table in db.Events
            where programs.Any(p => p.ID == table.ProgramID)
            select table;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ProgramID` column/property of `Events` is nullable (in the db). The `programs.Contains` check expects a `ListItem` that is not nullable.

Depending on whats appropriate in your situation you could change the `ProgramID` column/property of `Events` to not accept nulls, or you could cast `table.ProgramID` to a non nullable `ListItem`. (Or perhaps let `programs` be of a list of nullable ListItems: `List<ListItem?>`.)

Edit:
Aducci's is an elegant solution that nullifies ;-) my suggestions.

Comment: I haven't worked with linq-to-entities so I might be off on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void PopulateEvents(List<ListItem> programs) 
{     
       var rows = from table in db.Events.AsEnumerable()               
                  where programs.Cast<ListItem>().Select( y => y.Text).Contains(table.ProgramID.Value.ToString())                
                  select table; 
}
```